# unable to enter text in input box using Robot framework RIDE IDE

Tags: robotframework

Unable to enter text in input box using robot framework because of the error "InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it."

```
Open Browser    https://outlook.live.com/owa/    chrome
Maximize Browser Window
sleep    5
Click Element    Xpath=/html/body/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div
Input Text    Xpath=//[@id="i0281"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div    testing.sample@outlook.com
```

how to fix this issue???

python2.7 version
selenium 3.6.0

Comment: You're trying to input text on a `div` element, which by definition is not able to be edited - and that is what the error says. Check and fix your locator, it should end with `input`

Answer (score -1):

Here, ID field is changing, so using absolute xpath will resolve this issue, here is my working code ...

```
    *** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
RnD - Test1
    Open Browser    https://outlook.live.com/owa/    chrome
    Maximize Browser Window
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    Xpath=/html/body/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div    10
    Click Element    Xpath=/html/body/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//body/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/input[1]
    Input Text    //body/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/input[1]    testing.sample@outlook.com
```

Comment: How on Earth could you know that, and when an absolute xpath is the right solution? For the second part - whenever the page's DOM changes - by some user interaction and a js framework changes the elements, or in a future build something is modified in the tree, the abosolute path will fail instantly.

Comment: @ Todor, thanks, you are right, we can use other attribute of web-element those are constant, here we can use 
`Input Text name=loginfmt testing.sample@outlook.com`